# How to find Chessboard distance and city block distance between two points in an image matrix?

Tags: image-processing

Given here is a 5*5 image :

```
 3 2 4 3 1q
 0 4 4 3 2
 2 2 2 0 2
 2 2 1 1 1
1p 0 1 0 3
```

I am asked to find Euclidean distance, chessboard distance and city-block(Manhattan) distance between points 1p and 1q(p and q are subscripts).

No other information is provided.How do I find the distances stated above  in an image matrix?

Comment: Please try to be more specific about what your asking and properly define your term. If "city-block" is Manhattan distance, the obviously it is the width+height, 4+4=8.

Comment: Thank you for your reply! 
So basically you are considering unit distance between the pixels. That should give me chessboard distance = 4. Am I right?

Comment: This is is not a place where people do your homework.
Just search the internet for those terms, get their definition and apply them to your task...If you have difficulties explain what you don't understand and everyone will gladly help you